# How to differentiate between open source jars and commercial jars

Tags: java, jar

In our project , there are a lot of jars involved (approx 200). We need to identify between open source jars and commercial jars. I can apply the logic here but need to check how to go about it.

Can we check the manifest file or if inside a jar , there is a package which starts with org. , then can this be considered as open source ?

Comment: Is the source included in the jars that are open source?

Comment: @SteveSmith Whether source code is available or not has also nothing to do with the license.

Comment: Of course, but if there was a direct link between the jars that Aqeel has being open-source and them having the source code inside them, it would provide an easy solution.

Comment: We don't want to do it manually . We wanted to create some utility for this since we want to run these on a lot of projects.

Comment: @Aqeel Smith If only the open-source jars have the source code (which is a pretty big if), you could easily check for the existence of the .java files.  Jars use the zip file format.

Answer (score 4):

> Can we check the manifest file or if inside a jar , there is a package which starts with org. , then can this be considered as open source ?

Absolutely not. Package names have no relationship to licenses.

With 200 libraries it's probably easier to do it manually, otherwise search for "Open-Source compliance software". There are tools which check whether used libraries and/or code comply to your open-source policy.

Comment: So basically , there is no way of doing it by applying logic and using code  , it can only be done manually.

Comment: @AqeelSmith This is not what I said. I said it's probably easier for 200 libs to do it manually. There are software solutions which scan your dependencies or source code and check it for OS compliance. But it's not as easy as "package starts with org this must be open-source". You may probably also need to, like differentiate copyleft vs. permissive licenses, check for incompatible licenses etc. Open-source license compliance is a difficult problem. If you're small you can probably get it manually pretty well. If you're big, well, it will get complex and expensive.

Comment: @AqeelSmith This might get you started: http://go.linuxfoundation.org/open-source-compliance-ebook

Answer (score 0):

> there is a package which starts with org. , then can this be
>   considered as open source ?

It's customary that packages starting with `org.` should be open source but it's not mandatory. What differentiates open source from commercial is their license.

> Can we check the manifest file

Different `jar`s have license placed in different directory. There's no specified protocol.

For example,

- In the case of `apache commons` the license may be found in `apache-commons-lang.jar\META-INF\LICENSE.txt`.
- But for Google Guava, it's not like that. You can find license only on the headers of their source file as a comment. `META-INF` doesn't contain any `LICENSE.txt` file